# Angular 5: Karma Unit testing fails to start HeadlessChrome on CI environment

Tags: angular, jenkins, openshift, karma-runner, karma-chrome-launcher

We're facing issues on our CI environment (Jenkins within a Docker build pod on Openshift).

**Error: Failed to adjust OOM score of renderer with pid 261: Permission denied (13)**

Here some additionalinfos:

- Docker based build pod is running based on CentOS
- CustomLauncher created with --no-sandbox flag (see below)
- We are not able to run the pod as a root
- The error occurs intermittent. But most of the time it fails. Like in one of 10 jobs it works.
- If we execute the tests locally, everything works fine.

Versions:

- Angular version 5.1.0
- Karma-chrome-launcher 2.1.1
- Karma 1.70

`[31m22 01 2018 13:05:37.019:ERROR [launcher]: [39mChrome stdout: 
    [31m22 01 2018 13:05:37.019:ERROR [launcher]: [39mChrome stderr: 
    DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9222/devtools/browser/c45b2629-938e-490e-a8af-706302677ea4
    [0122/130522.747519:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(268)] Failed to adjust OOM score of renderer with pid 261: Permission denied (13)
    [0122/130533.563149:INFO:CONSOLE(8743)] "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.", source: http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/polyfills.bundle.js (8743)
    [0122/130533.563271:ERROR:service_manager.cc(157)] Connection InterfaceProviderSpec prevented service: content_renderer from binding interface: blink::mojom::ReportingServiceProxy exposed by: content_browser`

Karma.conf
`customLaunchers: {
         ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox: {
           base: 'ChromeHeadless',
           flags: [
             '--no-sandbox',
             '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
             '--remote-debugging-port=9222',
             '--disable-gpu'
           ]
         }
       }`

Comment: is it possible the port 9222 is being used by another build configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After we increased the memory of our build pod from 1GB to 2GB everything runs smooth now ....